# dask.map_partitions(..).compute() with expected 2Gb result size raises Memory error on 16Gb local machine

Tags: python, dask

Running code on Dask cluster through `map_partitions(...).compute()` expecting results of only cca 2Gb size.

Surprisingly, it fails with `MemoryError` on my local machine! Though, I am certainly using client for the remote cluster, the remote cluster`s dashboard is also showing that cluster is getting busy with this task, and cluster gets to its peak memory consumption as well (initially I thought that cluster's memory is the problem).

I wonder how it is  even possible, that memory issue happens on the local machine memory?
Expected result size is cca 2Gb, while my laptop has 16Gb.

```py
dask_client.upload_file(os.path.join(src_folder,'capacity.py'))
result = (read_parquets_separately_by_dask_and_concatenate('hub_to_hub_capacity/2021/10/')
    .map_partitions(capacity.capacity_features,
                    meta=meta_capacity_features,
                    transform_divisions=False)
).compute()
```

On Dask cluster (deployed in Azure) I have a file for every hour during the month. Dask is reading every file independently and concatenates them. And my expectation is that 'map_partitions` will process every file's chunk of data.
The same code for a single day (24 files) ran quickly and returned 70Mb pandas df as a result.

Error message shows my local paths to libraries. And I experience other application glitching because of memory issue. So, it is certain that problem happens locally:

```
distributed.protocol.core - CRITICAL - Failed to Serialize
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    frames[0] = msgpack.dumps(msg, default=_encode_default, use_bin_type=True)
  File "C:\Users\oleg.demidenko\.virtualenvs\interc_predict-5QmpLbYY\lib\site-packages\msgpack\__init__.py", line 35, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack\_packer.pyx", line 120, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.__cinit__
MemoryError: Unable to allocate internal buffer.
distributed.batched - ERROR - Error in batched write
Traceback (most recent call last):
 ...
  File "C:\Users\oleg.demidenko\.virtualenvs\interc_predict-5QmpLbYY\lib\site-packages\msgpack\__init__.py", line 35, in packb
    return Packer(**kwargs).pack(o)
  File "msgpack\_packer.pyx", line 120, in msgpack._cmsgpack.Packer.__cinit__
MemoryError: Unable to allocate internal buffer.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for Dask to construct a dataframe in your client as a result of a `compute()`, it needs to

- download a set of results from workers, encoded as bytestreams
- decode into in-memory pandas dataframes
- call `pd.concatenate` to stitch this into a single output.

While concatenating, the constituent dataframes must all be in the clients memory, and the incoming bytestreams might not have been freed yet, hence the memory spike. There has been work done to try to make the steps zero-copy, but I don't know the progress here. It is tricky with the public pandas API to assign the expected dataframe and write data directly into it (cf. fastparquet does do this, in complex and error-prone code!).

Really, a `.compute()` is meant for a much-aggregated final result. In all the advice on memory pressure, working with pandas dataframes (with or without dask) suggests you should always have "a few to many times" (depending on the process) the in-memory size of the data free to be able to operate smoothly.

-EDIT-

The traceback actually suggests that the problem happens on the worker whilst packing the dataframe to send to the client; but the same arguments apply.

Comment: I dind't get the last edit and why "same arguments apply". So, workers or scheduler do part of results concatenation, and only some part is left ot client? Is it possible to fix the issue I am facing by upgrading cluster or changing the code somehow? The only thing I can't change is my local client laptop. And it seems a weird issue if 16Gb laptop can't receive 2Gb results.

Comment: May be there is some doc on what you described in your answer? I tried to find smth, but failed.

Comment: Please give more info on `read_parquets_separately_by_dask_and_concatenate` and where it is running.

Comment: Can you tell if the exception is happening in the client or a worker?

Comment: The function is running on cluster, and it is approximately only this: `dask.dataframe.concatenate([dask.read_parquet() for path in paths])`. As I wrote in the question: those exceptions show my local client paths (laptop). And other apps on my laptop are crashing because of lack of memory.

Comment: Somehow, it successfuly computed a much bigger result today (2.5Gb). But it still runs very slow, and I am getting new warning message now. Not sure if it suggests lack of memory on cluster?
`distributed.client - WARNING - Couldn't gather 720 keys, rescheduling {"('capacity_features-884c83d93da2498a353aef6058113382', 81)": ('tcp://192.168.0.92:34787',)`

Comment: Are you SURE that your workload is running on the cluster?
That warning message probably means a worker died, check your logs.

Comment: You were right. Last time it crashed on the cluster side, instead of the client side. This happens to me when after the client failures cluster memory wasn't cleared. Calling `cluster.restart()` helped with it.
Thanks for your help!